# Prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{\sqrt{3a+b}}\le \sqrt{3(a+b+c)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that if $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ then $\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{\sqrt{3a+b}}\le \sqrt{3(a+b+c)}$
  The equality case seems to hold if $a=b=c$ so I was thinking of using AM-GM but cant operate in any creative ways. Please help or provide alternate solutions.

Comment: from whre does it come?

Comment: @above it was in a mock USAMO paper.

Comment: have you got a Link?

Comment: I am really sorry no. Actually someone gave me this problem saying the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By C-S $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{3a+b}}\right)^2\leq(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{3a+b}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{3a+b}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{3a+b}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\leq\frac{3}{4}-1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{3a+b}\geq\frac{3}{4},$$
which is true by C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{3a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2}{3ab+b^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3ab+b^2)}\geq\frac{3}{4}$$
because the last inequality it's just
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

we write the left-hand side as $$\left(\frac{2a}{3a+b}\sqrt{3a+b}+\frac{2b}{3b+c}\sqrt{3b+c}+\frac{2c}{3c+a}\sqrt{3c+a}\right)^2$$ and now we use CS and we get
$$\le \left(\left(\frac{2a}{3a+b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2b}{3b+c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2c}{3c+a}\right)^2\right)(4(a+b+c))\le 3(a+b+c)$$
this is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{2a}{3a+b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2b}{3b+c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2c}{3c+a}\right)^2\le \frac{3}{4}$$
we moving all to the right and multiplying out and we have:
$$-45\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+66\,{a}^{4}bc+11\,{a}^{4}{c}^{2}+66\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3
}-162\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}c+414\,{a}^{3}b{c}^{2}+66\,{a}^{3}{c}^{3}+11\,{a}
^{2}{b}^{4}+414\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}c-1050\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-162\,{a}^
{2}b{c}^{3}-45\,{a}^{2}{c}^{4}+66\,a{b}^{4}c-162\,a{b}^{3}{c}^{2}+414
\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{3}+66\,ab{c}^{4}-45\,{b}^{4}{c}^{2}+66\,{b}^{3}{c}^{3}+
11\,{b}^{2}{c}^{4}
\geq 0$$
setting $$b=a+u,c=a+u+v$$ and simplifying we get
$$\left( 512\,{u}^{2}+512\,uv+512\,{v}^{2} \right) {a}^{4}+ \left( 1536
\,{u}^{3}+2816\,{u}^{2}v+2304\,u{v}^{2}+512\,{v}^{3} \right) {a}^{3}+
 \left( 1568\,{u}^{4}+4160\,{u}^{3}v+3936\,{u}^{2}{v}^{2}+1344\,u{v}^{
3}+32\,{v}^{4} \right) {a}^{2}+ \left( 576\,{u}^{5}+2008\,{u}^{4}v+
2352\,{u}^{3}{v}^{2}+1008\,{u}^{2}{v}^{3}+88\,u{v}^{4} \right) a+32\,{
u}^{6}+152\,{u}^{5}v+219\,{u}^{4}{v}^{2}+110\,{u}^{3}{v}^{3}+11\,{u}^{
2}{v}^{4}
\geq 0$$
which is true.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong because the  inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a}{3a+b}\right)^2\leq\frac{3}{4}$ is wrong. Try $a=10$, $b=1$ and $c\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: i have forgotten to take the square root

Comment: hm i have with $$a=10,b=1$$ and $$c->0$$ $$\left(\frac{10}{31}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2=\frac{1861}{8649}<\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: It should be $\left(\frac{20}{31}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2<\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: where is the $2$ in your left hand side?

Comment: Firstly I divided by $2$ both sides.